# SharePoint2010 chrometype modification

Tags: sharepoint-2010, frontend, branding

I am setting up a webdesign and the headers of the webpart titles is to be designed with an image which has bowed corners. The issue is that the webparts can have dynamical widths. I used FireBug to check how the webpart headers is constructed and found 2 TD on each side of the header

```
<tr class="ms-WPHeader">    
    <td align="left" class="ms-wpTdSpace">    ...    <td align="left" class="ms-wpTdSpace">
</tr>
```

These 2 I can use to put in the bowed corners to make the rest of the headers background dynamical in width.

So - I wondered where I can find the file which constructs the "Default" Chrome Type?

Answer (score 0):

It's not done by any file. It's done inside the ASP.NET and SharePoint assemblies. You need to create a Control Adapter and create custom rendering for the Web Parts.

Answer (score 0):

Just style the heck out of the wrappers that you find wrapping your web part. Then use the sliding doors method with an image with your rounded corners.

If you want a real challenge, try to make them dynamic width wise AND height wise.  ;)

Comment: This is actually an interesting question.  Have you found an answer?